# Tkinter: Barra de progreso

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, progressbar

Tengo un programa en **python** en el cual quiero insertar una barra de progreso, que vaya acorde al tiempo de ejecución del método **inpt()**. En mi código la barra va incrementando de 1 en 1 su valor, no se  rige por ningún variable ni nada por el estilo.
Me gustaría saber, ya que no he encontrado información al respecto, si se puede crear una barra que dure lo que dura la ejecución del método al ejecutarlo desde el botón **b1**.

Dejo el código que tengo por aqui:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import sys, time

window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry("250x105") 
window.geometry("+900+400")
window.configure(bg='#9EB9DF')
window.title('INPUT')
window.iconphoto(False, tk.PhotoImage(file='C:/input.png'))
 
def inpt():
    global e
    global string
    string = e.get()
    print("Hola " + string)
    return string

def ext():
    sys.exit()

def OnHover(button, colorOnHover, colorOnLeave): 
    button.bind("<Enter>", func=lambda e: button.config(background=colorOnHover))  
    button.bind("<Leave>", func=lambda e: button.config(background=colorOnLeave))

def increment(*args):
    for i in range(100):
        p1["value"] = i+1
        window.update()
        time.sleep(0.1)
        
e = Entry(window,font='ProductSans 11 bold', width=31, borderwidth=1, relief=GROOVE , justify=CENTER)
e.grid()
e.focus_set()

b1 = tk.Button(window, text='FUNCTION 1', fg='black', bg='WHITE', relief=GROOVE, height = 1, width = 30, font='ProductSans 10 bold', command=inpt)
b1.grid()
b2 = tk.Button(window, text='FUNCTION 2', fg='black', bg='WHITE' ,relief=GROOVE, height = 1, width = 30, font='ProductSans 10 bold')
b2.grid()
b3 = tk.Button(window, text='FUNCTION 3', fg='black', bg='WHITE' ,relief=GROOVE, height = 1, width = 30, font='ProductSans 10 bold', command=ext)
b3.grid()
p1 = ttk.Progressbar(window, length=200, mode="determinate", orient=tk.HORIZONTAL)
p1.grid(row=4,column=0)

btn = ttk.Button(window,text="Start",command=increment)
btn.grid(row=5,column=0)

OnHover(b1, "#F4F4F4", "white")
OnHover(b2, "#F4F4F4", "white")
OnHover(b3, "#F4F4F4", "white")

window.mainloop()

print ("Outside "+string)
```

### Actualización

Ya he entendido que no se puede hacer lo que pido ya que el programa no puede calcular el tiempo que va a tardar en ejecutarse la función. Que alternativa tengo para hacerlo lo mas exacto posible? Se me ocurre añadir un `sleep()` de x segundos para que tarde en ejecutarse y a la barra de progreso añadirle el mismo tiempo. ¿Que alternativas habría?

Comment: Las barras de progreso no pueden adivinar cuánto va a tardar en ejecutarse una función cualquiera para adaptarse a ello. Lo normal es que tu código sepa de antemano el tiempo aproximado que será necesario y vaya incrementando la barra según el tiempo transcurrido, o que si por ejemplo se trata de procesar un conjunto de datos, cada cierto tiempo se pueda saber cuántos han sido ya procesados (y el total de ellos) para pintar una barra proporcional al porcentaje completado. En definitiva, tu función tiene que "informar" de alguna forma del % que lleva, y usar esa información para la barra.

Comment: ¿Se podría ejecutar desde que inicia hasta que finaliza la función?

Comment: Claro, pero el problema es, a medida que va pasando el tiempo ¿qué porcentaje de la barra vas rellenando? Por ejemplo, imagina que tu función va a tardar en terminar 10 segundos. Cada segundo que pasa deberías avanzar la barra un 10%, Pero sin saber de antemano que va a tardar 10s no puedes conocer qué porcentaje avanzar cada segundo. Debería ser la propia función la que, a medida que va completando su ejecución, va notificando a la barra la cantidad a avanzar.

Answer (score 2):

Quien realmente sabe mejor el tiempo que le queda para terminar es la propia función, y por tanto debería ser esa función la que actualice la barra de progreso.

Una función que va a tardar en ejecutarse normalmente es porque contiene algún tipo de bucle. Por ejemplo imagina que la función tiene que leer un fichero y procesar su contenido. Un caso típico sería leer el fichero línea a línea. Si la función determina antes cuántas líneas hay en el fichero (por ejemplo hay 100), entonces en cada iteración de su bucle sabe que habrá completado un 1% del trabajo total (una línea de 100). Con esa información puede ir actualizando la barra de progreso.

Otro ejemplo, si la función está ejecutando un comando externo vía `os.system()` o similar, es posible que ese comando externo tenga también algún indicador de progreso, como por ejemplo el ir mostrando en la salida estándar el % completado. La función entonces podría usar `os.popen()` en vez de `os.system()` para poder acceder a la salida estándar del comando mientras éste se va ejecutando. De esa salida estándar podría obtener mediante algún procesamiento de cadenas el trozo que dice el porcentaje completado, y usar ese trozo para actualizar la barra de progreso.

Para que veas un ejemplo más concreto con código, el siguiente programa muestra una entrada de texto, una barra de progreso y un botón. Al pulsar el botón se va a ejecutar una función que va a repetir un bucle tantas veces como indiques en la entrada de texto. Así estaríamos emulando por ejemplo la lectura de un fichero con tantas líneas como le pongas ahí. En cada repetición del bucle la función contiene un `time.sleep()` de medio segundo, para simular el tiempo perdido en leer esa línea y procesarla.

Así, si pones como número 10, la función ejecutará el bucle 10 veces y tardará por tanto 5 segundos en terminar, pero si pones 100 tardará 50 segundos.

La función es la encargada de ir actualizando la barra de progreso, para lo que calcula qué porcentaje del trabajo total ha terminado ya (será el contador del bucle dividido entre el total de repeticiones, y por 100)

```
from tkinter import Tk, HORIZONTAL, LEFT, RIGHT, mainloop
from tkinter.ttk import Progressbar, Entry, Button, Frame, Label
import time

tk=Tk()

# Entrada del numero
frame = Frame(tk)
frame.pack(pady=10, padx=10)
lbl= Label(frame, text="Repeticiones")
lbl.pack(side=LEFT, padx=5)
txt = Entry(frame, width=6)
txt.pack(side=RIGHT)

# Barra de progreso
progress=Progressbar(tk,orient=HORIZONTAL,mode='determinate')
progress.pack(padx=5, fill="x")


# Boton y función asociada al pulsarlo
def funcion():
  try:
    repetir = int(txt.get())
  except:
    return
  for i in range(repetir):
    progress['value']=i/repetir*100
    tk.update_idletasks()
    time.sleep(0.5)
  progress['value'] = 100

Button(tk,text='Run',command=funcion).pack(fill="x", padx=5)

# Bucle principal
mainloop()
```

Aqui tienes un video de una ejecución en la que meto un par de valores para probar:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]